# Sorted List Array Question

Tags: arrays, sorting

Is it possible that two sorted list of size n/2 each can be merged using n/2 size of working ?array???

Comment: i am interested why is it "not a real question"?

Comment: You can do this in-place, without using any workspace (apart from two array indexes). If you start with sorted arrays a[m] and b[n], you can rearrange them so that a and b are still sorted, and a[m-1] <= b[0]. Is this what you want? If so, I can elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

That has not impact on complexity O(n). 
You can not get n/2 all the time. 
A= [1,2,3,10]
B= [4,5,6,8]

You need n-1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean working array as in the extra storage required over and above the final array, you don't even need that. To sort two lists which are *already* sorted, you only need to merge them and that requires only two values (one per source list) rather than `n/2`.

The algorithm is as follows:

```
create empty list newlist
set idx1 to start of list1
set idx2 to start of list2
while idx1 within list1 or idx2 within list2:
    if idx1 beyond list1:
        append list2[idx2] to newlist
        increment idx2
    else if idx2 beyond list2:
        append list1[idx1] to newlist
        increment idx1
    else if list1[idx1] is less than list2[idx2]:
        append list1[idx1] to newlist
        increment idx1
    else:
        append list2[idx2] to newlist
        increment idx2
```

If you mean "Can you combine two `n/2`-size arrays into another `n/2`-size array?" then, short of doing some trickery where you can combine two elements into one (such as tow 16-bit integers into a 32-bit element), no, it's not possible.